# when XMLHttpRequest gets deallocated?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, javascript-objects

Let's see the code (that's entire html page)

```
<script>
function ajax_async(method, url, body, cb) {
  var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
  r.open(method, url, true);
  r.onreadystatechange = cb;
  r.send(body);
}

ajax_async('GET', '/sleep.php', null, function() {
  if(this.readyState==4) alert('123');
});
</script>
```

sleep.php just sleeps 10 sec and returns

Obviously, XMLHttpRequest object uses some memory and should be deallocated after use if we want long-living application page. As I know, javascript uses garbage collector to free unused items in memory, and "unused" means "can't be accessed".

In the code above, the variable `r` is local and can't be accessed outside `ajax_async()` function. But the request continues to work and the callback function called after 10 sec, so the XMLHttpRequest object still exists and didn't deallocated. Why? Will it be deallocated after readyState becomes 4? If no, when it will be? If yes, why, is readyState==4 means "deallocatable" and others values "deallocatable", is this specified somewhere?

Comment: `r.onreadystatechange` keeps the reference in the event queue. I doubt `r` being garbage collected before the event will be removed.

Comment: but the event (received response) happens only 10 seconds later

Comment: Yes, but firing an event doesn't remove it, it's still there ready to fire again if needed. In the past, events attached to the DOM elements were complicated when an element was removed. This is mostly solved in modern JS engines, I'd assume XHR objects can be and are handled similarly.